# Is it safer to create database user with SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE rights in MySQL for php script?

Tags: mysql

I have a php scripts "Web sites" I want to create a dedicated user for all of my of my PHP scripts. All of my scripts do SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE and DELETE so I am thinking to add a user with only DATA privileges. Will it be okay to do that? I am not sure if I need more rights like INDEX "to use indexes?"  Lock Tables?

Comment: what's a `DATA` privilege? That's not a mysql privilege: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html  `INDEX` priv is for creating/dropping privs. you do not need ANY special privilege to be able to USE indexes.

Comment: Data is the group of "SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE" as clasified in phpmyadmin